# Passing Additional Arguments in javascript map es6

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to pass in an additional parameter to the callback function in a map. The value is not passed when I use es6 syntax for callback function and in map.

Here is the es6 map and callback function

```js
const convertEvents = action.payload.map(item => convertEvent(item), { role: 'teacher' });

const convertEvent = (item) => {
    console.log('----------convertEvent role----------');
    console.log(this.role);
    return item;
};
```

But when I used old javascript syntax the value is passed and the code works correctly

```js
const convertEvents = action.payload.map(convertEventRole, { role: 'teacher' });

function convertEventRole(item) {
    console.log('----------convertEvent role----------');
    console.log(this.role);
    return item;
}
```

Can you tell me why the es6 code didn't work?

Comment: I'd suggest looking up with the main feature of `=>` is in ES6 (hint it has to do with the value of `this`).  It is not just a shortcut.  It has a functionality difference too.  There are hundreds of articles on this feature you can read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. I will study more about arrow functions.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling for the reference. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd parameter passed to `Array.map()` is the `thisArg`, which is:

```
Value to use as this when executing callback.
```

With a standard JS `function`, `this` is defined by execution context, but you can change it using `Function.bind()`, and other methods.

An arrow function `this` is defined by the context in which it's declared, and thus cannot be changed. That's why you can use the assigned `thisArg` with an arrow function.

You can approximate the functionality using [partial application](http://benalman.com/news/2012/09/partial-application-in-javascript/) and [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

const result = arr.map(((m) => (n) => n + m)(5));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. I have been replacing all my functions with new es6 syntax and now I know there is a clear difference between them. I should read more about arrow functions I guess.

Comment: Welcome :) The main feature of arrow functions (beyond being shorter) is the scope of `this`, so you should read about lexical scoping. This seems to be a nice article about [arrow functions and lexical scope](https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/).